# Email sent by Wildfly/JBoss can't be verified by Gmail

Tags: java, email, jboss, smtp, wildfly

I'm having issues regarding the trustworthiness of a email a Java EE server of mine sends to it's users, Gmail can not guarantee  that the email comes from where it's header claims to.

My setup is Wildfly 9 and a localhost sendmail.

**The Main sender Java class code:**

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/mail/Default")

(...)

public void send() throws Exception {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(mySession);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    Address toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(message);
}
```

**Wildfly's /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml:**

```
 <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
     <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
 </outbound-socket-binding>

(...)

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
    <mail-session name="default" from="noreply@<my domain>" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
        <smtp-server ssl="true" outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
    </mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

**When the email is received at Gmail (and the user hoovers the cursor at the "?" profile picture):**

> Gmail couldn't verify that  actually sent this message (and not a spammer).

That setup is repeated in multiple forums regarding a Wildfly service's mail function.

I've noticed that other applications (non-JBoss) can send emails through the localhost's sendmail just fine, having it's domain verified by Gmail. So I assume something is lacking on my Java/Wildfly/Jboss configuration.

The exact mail signature (the one configured at the Java code and the one configured and the XML file).

Can you folks help me?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: The program that generates the email is not the problem.  Do you have SPF and/or DKIM records for your domain?  Are you sending from your own IP address?  Email delivery can be a difficult thing as everyone wants to avoid spam.  You'll do better to use a service like Sendgrid or Amazon SES or others.